# How to copy one row to multiple rows?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have to build a list that combines processes and countries.

I have 114 processes and 55 countries.

I have to build the list like this:

- First process 55 times (55 countries)
- Second process 55 times (55 countries)
- ... etc.

Example:
[image]

I am thinking about this code:

```vb
Sub Copydata()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row
    
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Dim A
    
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        For y = 1 To 55
            Sheet3.Cells(y, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
        Next y
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

This should add to Sheet 3, 55 times process 1 then move to process 2 etc. (I can handle the country part, afterwards.)

I get

> runtime error 1004

Comment: `xlUp` - it's the letter `l`, not the number `1`. Note that you can use `Resize` here instead of your inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. The one that is causing your runtime error is a typo of the vba const `xlUp` which you have as `x1Up` (the number 1 instead of the letter l).

In addition, you can clean things up a bit by using your variables more consistently. Grab references to your sheets either through the Workbook or though the sheet code names. In your code you do both. I also like to see more explicit value assignment on the Cells objects. Instead of setting the cells equal to each other, set the `Cell.Value`. Here's the slight modifications that I suggest:

EDIT:
I've updated the code to do what you are describing in your comment.

```
Sub Copydata()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    lastrow = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    y = 1
    
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        For y = y To y + 54
            sht3.Cells(y, 1).Value = sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next y
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the code, after replacing the number with the letter the code worked and also your code worked. the issue that I am facing with right now is that the code is overwriting the lines over and over instead of adding below. I presume a need a 3rd letter to use in the code for it to add process 2 after the first 55 lines of process1 and process3 after that and so on until i get 6270 lines

Comment: @TudorDobre so, are you wanting sheet3 to have 55 rows all set to the value of the first row of sheet2? And then rows 56 - 110 all set to the value of the second row of sheet2? and so on? I've updated the answer to do what I think you are describing. You simply don't restart `y` to 1 each loop.